# How to target image with certain src path with JQuery

Tags: jquery, src, attr

How would I go about targeting the below img with the src file?

```
<img src="left1.gif" alt="" />
```

`$('img[src=left1.gif]').hide();` doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the string value of src in your selector.  This helps resolves ambiguities with special characters, and seems to apply to the `.` in the filename.

```
$("img[src='left1.gif']").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks Zombat, you saved me a few more hairs on my head :)

Comment: Np, I've run into that one before.  I've trained myself to always quote all attribute selector values now  ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your HTML says l**e**ft1.gif, but your jQuery says l**i**ft1.gif. Note also the quotes around my value:

```
$("img[src='left1.gif']").hide();
```